# Django Rest Framework URL Patterns

Tags: python, django, oauth, django-rest-framework

So i am just messing around with Django rest framework and trying to install oauth2. Can I have 2 url patterns like my url.py below or should it be like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^$', 'memories_app.views.home', name='home'),
            url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
            url(r'^o/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),
            url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
            url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
     ]
```

#### When I do this I get error:

> url(r'^', include(router.urls)), ^
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax and my site wont load.

`urls.py`

```
 from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls import include, url
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', 'memories_app.views.home', name='home'),
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^o/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),
        url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
        ]


    # Serializers define the API representation.
    class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'is_staff')

    # ViewSets define the view behavior.
    class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer_class = UserSerializer

    # Routers provide an easy way of automatically determining the URL conf.
    router = routers.DefaultRouter()
    router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)

    # Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
    # Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
        url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the comma before `router.urls` line. The correct block should be:

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', 'memories_app.views.home', name='home'),
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^o/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),
  url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')), # Here
  url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
  ]
```

Comment: Oh duhh thanks! i hate when that happens lol